# Repeat elements of vector in R

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to repeat the elements of vector a, b number of times. That is, a="abc" should be "aabbcc" if y = 2.

Why doesn't either of the following code examples work?

```
sapply(a, function (x) rep(x,b))
```

and from the plyr package,

```
aaply(a, function (x) rep(x,b))
```

I know I'm missing something very obvious ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you `a` is a vector, sapply will create a matrix that just needs to be collapsed back into a vector:

```
a<-c("a","b","c")
b<-3 # Or some other number
a<-sapply(a, function (x) rep(x,b))
a<-as.vector(a)
```

Should create the following output:

```
"a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c"
```

Comment: Forgot about collapsing it. This obviously works. Not sure why plyr's aaply doesn't. Oh well.

Answer (score 17):

`a` is not a vector, you have to split the string into single characters, e.g.

```
R> paste(rep(strsplit("abc","")[[1]], each=2), collapse="")
[1] "aabbcc"
```

Comment: The "each=" argument to rep is notable, too. :-)

Comment: I made a mistake in my writeup of the question, a was indeed meant to be a vector, eg a=c("a","b","c"). If it weren't, your solution is obviously correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option with `gsub/strrep` in `base R`

```
gsub("(.)", strrep("\\1", 2), a)
#[1] "aabbcc"
```

#### data

```
a <- 'abc'
```